# In routes, override scope-defined name from w/in the scope block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

Imagine you've created a scope for a bunch of routes:

```
scope 'author', as: 'author' do
  get 'search'     => 'author#search'
  get 'publishers' => 'author#publishers'
  get 'books'      => 'author#my_books', as: 'my_books'
  get 'stores'     => 'author#stores'
end
```

The scope will naturally create paths for each of the requests; e.g., `search` will have a path called `author_search_path`.

How might you override the inclusion of the scope in the path, from within the scope block?  For instance, the `books` is renamed as `my_books`, but the scope makes it `author_my_books_path`.  Is it possible to rename the path as `my_books_path` (without the `author_`) without moving the line outside the scope block?

Because `author` isn't a resource, I don't think shallowness or collections can be used.

---

***Note:*** The above is not actual data, but only an example to comply with privacy rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I can't think of a way to do it without moving it outside the `scope` block. Here's what I would put after that `scope` block:

```
get 'author/books' => 'author#my_books', as: 'my_books'
```

Comment: Thank you, Ryan.  It's a shame as I was hoping to refactor the code to make it more readable, but it seems this would break the routes.  Having lines outside the code looks partially messy.. then there's the whole order/priority (FIFO) factor.